# Outlook Add-in iframe dialog - only content resizes

Tags: outlook, ms-office, outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins

I am developing Outlook add-in and displaying a dialog with option `displayInIframe: true` and height and width parameters given. However I have experienced a problem using add-in in outlook.com via browser. Although it works good when screen has a standard proportion (width>height), it looks bad when I resize the window and make it narrow (height>width). Then, the content is resized and pushed to the side of the frame while the iframe itself stays with the same size.

[image: Standard window] [image: narrow window]

The question is if I can do something with that or its a Outlook issue. If so, I would like to notify MSFT about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior of a web application, you cant do much except setting the min-width for your html page so that it does not look that bad.
you can do some css changes to make the page look better for height/width in question.

Comment: The problem is that it resizes only content of the frame.

Comment: To me it looks like a CSS issue. Inspect the content of the iframe you can find some clues.

Comment: We could not repro this issue with a different page in the dialog. Looks like an issue with your css.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT, it is not the error with my CSS, because the whole iframe works like that, and i can modify only content of it. Please verify it and open a dialog, then resize the window. You'll notice that `div` with class `ms-Dialog-content` size stays the same, but its child `div` size changes to match width set by me.

Comment: Let me know if you want a screenshot of Chrome developer tools.

Comment: A plunker/fiddle with iframe would help

Comment: @Niko where you able to solve this issue ?